# Doesn't, Don't or not?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-request, word-order, word-difference

I have a simple question of English.
This is correct?

> The type "red" doesn't exist.

Or "not" or "don't"? And why?

> The type "red" ______ exist.
>
> 1. doesn't
> 2. not
> 3. don't

I know what "does" is use if the person is "he, she, it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't is simply a contraction of does not. They are interchangeable, with does not preferred in written language and doesn't in spoken language. In terms of meaning, they are 100% equivalent.

Don't is a contraction of do not. This can be used as an instruction to a person "Don't do that!" / "Do not do that!" or when referring to plural things "Male bees don't have a sting" / "Male bees do not have a sting".

In your example the colour red is an 'it' so the correct answer is 'The type Red doesn't (or does not) exist'.

Comment: "In your example the colour red is an 'it' so the correct answer is 'The type Red doesn't (or does not) exist'."Exact!, I need this!, thank you bro!.

Comment: "Does not" isn't always preferred in written language. However, it may be preferred in some formal contexts. Language register is more important than medium.